# Referenceable<T>: A Java Generic Class Used for Creating Objects That can be Mutated

Tags: java, reference

```
public class Referenceable<T> {
    private T obj;
    
    private Referenceable(T t) { obj = t; }
    
    public static <U> Referenceable<U> ref(U u){
        return new Referenceable<U>(u);
    }
    public T dereference() {
        return obj;
    }
    public T dereference(T newT) {   // Should be used for reassigning underlying object
        return obj = newT;
    }
}
```

This simple class allows functions like swap or exchange to be implemented for non-primitive types generically. An example implementation of swap with `Referenceable`:

```
<T> void swap(Referenceable<T> first, Referenceable<T> second){
    var tmp = first.dereference();
    first.dereference(second);
    second.dereference(tmp);
}
```

Here is example usage:

```
Referenceable<Integer> ri1 = Referenceable.ref(new Integer(21)), 
    ri2 = Referenceable.ref(new Integer(42)), 
    rn = Referenceable.ref(null);              // can reference null objects
System.out.prinln(ri1.dereference().toString(), ri2.dereference().toString());
SomeUtilClass.swap(ri1, ri2);
System.out.prinln(ri1.dereference().toString(), ri2.dereference().toString());
rn.dereference(new Integer(69)); // more efficient than rn = Referenceable.ref(new Integer(69)
Integer i = rn.dereference();
```

**Questions:**

1. `Referenceable` is a bit of mouthful: should I change the name?
2. Should I directly use the constructor instead of a factory function?
3. Could `Optional` replace `Referenceable`, making my class useless?
4. Though I doubt it, is there any way for me to make the syntax look something more like this:

   ```
   Referenceable<Integer> ri1 = new Integer(21),  // Automatically wraps into Referenceable.ref(new Integer(21))
       ri2 = new Integer(42),                     // ditto
       rn = Referenceable.ref(null);              // ref required because of ambiguity
   System.out.prinln(ri1.dereference().toString(), ri2.dereference().toString()); //dereference required so Referenceable.toString() is not called
   SomeUtilClass.swap(ri1, ri2);
   System.out.prinln(ri1.dereference().toString(), ri2.dereference().toString()); // ditto
   Integer i = rn;
   ```

Comment: This is not pass-by-reference. This is just mutation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Changed the title to be less misleading.

Comment: I don't quite understand the usecase behind the code. Why would you need this in the first place? Making pointer semantics explicit in Java is counter to the basic language design goal of hiding pointers. Reintroducing them feels like you're trying very hard to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Vogel612 The use case is supposed to be when you have an object that you want to allow functions you pass it to make changes. No, I am not shooting myself in the foot :)

Comment: FYI: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableObject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a class holding a single generic field with getter (`dereference()`) and setter (`dereference(T newT)`). As you have mentioned it is very much like `Optional` - except for intention behind its creation.

It seems to be quite **meta** - I would expect to see something like that in cases where we have some kind of self-building code - like specific instructions flow being decided during runtime (so not very procedural).

Obviously it can be useful (as much as `Optional` is) - but its rather hard to judge it without specific context - like, are you sure that effort added with wrapping the objects in additional abstraction (and the added indirection layer making reasoning a little more difficult) is worth it? Maybe there are other approaches to be considered?

Answering your questions to the best of my knowledge:

1. You can probably shorten it to `Ref` - as it is pretty well known term in programming in general (then I'd rename factory method in style similar to optional: `Ref.of(value)`). Or even `Reference`. I'd expect `able` suffix to be in the interface name rather than concrete class. Shorter and such generic name might clash with other classes (in java standard lib there are already both `Reference` and `Ref` classes) - its difficult to find the right balance in terms of naming.
2. Depends. Are you planing to publish (so that you will not have control over usages of the code) it in some kind of way (like it being part of some library)? If yes, then probably adding additional abstraction layer over creation is a good practice - so that you have extra flexibility as a library author. If usages of the class are fully controlled by you then you can simply use constructor and relay on some modern IDE to help you introducing static factory method if ever necessary (btw. book Effective Java Item 1 describes why someone could want to use static factory method - maybe there are actual use-case specific things that would make it preferable).
3. Probably not. Optional does not have built-in swap functionality - and the value it refers to is not mutable (so you can't really implement it in the same way as in your case). It also has (probably, as I am not sure of yours) different intention behind it - it handles problem of **presence** of some value - likely result of some operation.
4. I don't know any ways to do it (unless you want to init list of referencables). Also I don't think this is much of an improvement in terms of readability - personally I'd rather see wrapping being explicit and such auto-boxing/casting-ish seems magical to me and hard to explain for newcomers to the code.